# Visualizing Linear Transformations with Sage

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, mathematica, sagemath

Perhaps this isn't the best place to ask this, but there is no Sage specific stackexchange, so here I am.

I would like to be able to produce the geometric effect of a linear transformation, either on the plane or $\mathbb{R}^3$ (preferably both), to aid in a final paper and presentation this semester. Most of the widgets I've found online are lacking. I'd like to have more personalization options than you can find in
https://www.geogebra.org/m/ssO8VOrw
or
https://shadanan.github.io/MatVis/.

I'd like to be able to implement the code for transforming the cat face in Mathematica, found here
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46392/visualization-of-matrix-transformations,
in Sage (or CoCalc, whichever). I've never used Mathematica and don't have access to it on my personal machine, and implementing this in Sage seems outside of my current abilities. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not in the stack exchange network, but this is the equivalent of a sage stack exchange: https://ask.sagemath.org/questions/

Comment: I think this can be accomplished with just LaTeX by using pgfplot's coordinate transformation commands.  See section 25.3 (p. 362 in particular) of the [TikZ/PGF manual](http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do this.  [Here is a 2D example](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJydklGLnDAUhd8F_4MPCyZOduvsdl4KgR1Y9rn0VUSyenVCYyI3d2Zrf33jiLbS7UJXiJAc73dPjveikKWU8jh61JYAVU1x1ECbVOwoe0Wof7BvT8-iKPYiL0WRi31ZcqHO5Krz0CgC-ayMB_4ljpLwDMbIY3aBmhwydpvfHURYnC8qbtWHjYp_1v4l4kbccA20VMEI0mgLrAgmRGhV8t3gwq3YtPf6J8jD7xNcTmYC6u60QWBAIJaidsahTDsEsOlajgvwXzq-rc_NenemkxwUqh5CwnU1GEdsvV1BIgnZ7A-Z15bdZ4POiE9RhuATNosHEUc5X-gIzdT7o8D8muUCc6hsB4vXVtXwjtXaeUZcTFziARdHV96gP92vwBej6u_v-nuTMjHCa8UYdQHbAH6EJB6yjaV6VPa_OIEyI8QU38rxGqxVS1Zf5TpGu2Ukd1OAu-sfnz86UW9Y6nttYEy685hQyNu3DntokpcxuTnerLw7f3KvTPkhuKpQkXZyL1rdXWfrM_8FoZspUQ==&lang=sage), not original to me.

```
var('t')
@interact
def _(A=matrix(RDF,[[1,0],[0,1]]),auto_update=False):
    pll=A*vector((-0.5,0.5))
    plr=A*vector((-0.3,0.5))
    prl=A*vector((0.3,0.5))
    prr=A*vector((0.5,0.5))
    left_eye=line([pll,plr])+point(pll,size=5)+point(plr,size=5)
    right_eye=line([prl,prr],color='green')+point(prl,size=5,color='green')+point(prr,size=5,color='green')
    mouth=parametric_plot(A*vector([t, -0.15*sin(2*pi*t)-0.5]), (t, -0.5,
0),color='red')+parametric_plot(A*vector([t, -0.15*sin(2*pi*t)-0.5]), (t,0,0.5),color='orange')
    face=parametric_plot(A*vector([cos(t),sin(t)]),
(t,0,pi/2),color='black')+parametric_plot(A*vector([cos(t),sin(t)]),
(t,pi/2,pi),color='lavender')+parametric_plot(A*vector([cos(t),sin(t)]),
(t,pi,3*pi/2),color='cyan')+parametric_plot(A*vector([cos(t),sin(t)]),(t,3*pi/2,2*pi),color='sienna')
    P=right_eye+left_eye+face+mouth
    html('smiley guy transformed by $A$')
    P.show(aspect_ratio=1,figsize=4)
```

Comment: (And yes, you will get much quicker response on Sage stuff on ask.sagemath.org!)